# My counter is not giving my the correct value

Tags: javascript, counter

**ABOUT PROGRAM**

I'm creating a program that calculates how many weeks it takes for a person to lose weight, from the ***current weight*** to their ***target weight***, given a weight loss of 1.38kg a week.

The program prompts the user for their ***current weight*** and their ***target weight*** and displays an invalid error message if the *current weight* or ***target weight*** (or both) are 0 or less.

The program will also check if the ***current weight*** is greater than ***target weight*** and display the appropriate error message if the ***current weight*** is not greater than the ***target weight***.

**MY PROBLEM**

If the ***current weight*** is greater than the ***target weight***, a loop should be performed to reduce the ***current weight*** by 1.38kg. The loop should continue until the ***current weight*** is less than or equal to the ***target weight***. A counter should keep track of how many times the loop has been performed... this indicates the number of weeks it will take to reach the ***target weight***...

BUT I EVERY TIME I RUN THE PROGRAM I DONT GET THE CORRECT RESULT.

Below is an example of 2 weights and the correct number of weeks.

Current weight: 87
Target weight: 64
Weeks: 17

```js
var current_weight = 0.0
var target_weight = 0.0
var weeks = 0

current_weight = prompt("What is your current weight?")
target_weight = prompt("What is your target weight?")

if (current_weight > 0 && target_weight > 0) {
  if (current_weight > target_weight) {
    while (current_weight <= target_weight); {
      current_weight = (current_weight - 1.38);
      weeks = weeks + 1;
    }
    alert("It will take " + weeks + " weeks for you to achieve your target!")
  } else {
    alert("Your current weight must be MORE than the target weight!");
  }
} else {
  alert("Invalid entry.")
}
```

**What did I do wrong??**

Comment: your second `if` checks to see if the current weight is greater than the target weight, but the `while` loop only runs when the current weight is *smaller* than the target weight.

Answer (score 1):

`while (current_weight <= target_weight);` Will run the loop while the current weight is below the target, which above says it cannot be, so the loop will never run. I reversed the symbol and it runs correctly.

```js
var current_weight = 0.0
var target_weight = 0.0
var weeks = 0

current_weight = prompt("What is your current weight?")
target_weight = prompt("What is your target weight?")

if (current_weight > 0 && target_weight > 0) {
  if (current_weight > target_weight) {
    while (current_weight >= target_weight) {
      current_weight = (current_weight - 1.38);
      weeks = weeks + 1;
    }
    alert("It will take " + weeks + " weeks for you to achieve your target!")
  } else {
    alert("Your current weight must be MORE than the target weight!");
  }
} else {
  alert("Invalid entry.")
}
```